I have a raspberry pi3 and i want to use the ethernet port on my pi to send ethernet connection to my laptop
Is it possible to use my raspberry pi3 like a USB ethernet adapter to send ethernet through to my laptop using a USB, I dont care if the network isn't crazy fast I just want to play games on my laptop

You can't "send Ethernet" which describes the physical interface which the Pi3A doesn't have.

why don't you use the laptop's ethernet port?

You have not described what you want to do. Read this for guidance on how to ask technical questions: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro
